# Why am I not table to get sorted result in select?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following table:

```
DEST_COUNTRY_NAME   ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME count
United States       Romania             15
United States       Croatia             1
United States       Ireland             344
Egypt               United States       15
```

The table is represented as a `Dataset`.

```
scala> dataDS
res187: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[FlightData] = [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string ... 1 more field]
```

The following query to sort a Dataset based on `count` column works. I am getting the `count` column, sorting it and showing the result:

```
scala> dataDS.sort($"count".desc).show;
```

But if I try to use `select` then it doesn't work. Why?

```
scala> dataDS.select(dataDS.col("count").desc).show()
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: input[0, int, true] DESC NULLS LAST
```

I have several questions around this:

1. What is the purpose of `sort` because to me it seems the ordering is done by `col("..").desc`? Does `sort` just converts a `Column` datatype to a `Dataset`?
2. Why doesn't using `select` work? My logic is (a) create a descending order of column `dataDS.col("count").desc`, (b) `select` it and (c) `show` it. The reason I expected this to work is because a similar sql query will work `mysql> select count from flight_data_2015 ORDER BY count DESC;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason I expected this to work is because a similar sql query will work `mysql> select count from flight_data_2015 ORDER BY count DESC;`

But it isn't the same.

`select(dataDS.col("count").desc)` would be like `SELECT count DESC FROM dataDS`. Notice there is no `ORDER BY` clause.

This is what `.orderBy` or `.sort` in SparkSQL are doing, i.e. `dataDS.sort($"count".desc).show;` would be `SELECT * FROM dataDS ORDER BY count DESC`.

Also, note you could literally write `dataDS.sql("SELECT ... ")` (after registering the temp view) and it would have the same performance as doing it the other way.

---

`Dataset.sort` takes a list of `Column` objects within that Dataset, but it isn't converting them, only returning a new sorted `Dataset`

Comment: Thanks. I am confused because ‘desc’ is a method of ‘Column’. So  if I am already doing ‘col(“”).desc’, then ‘sort’ looks redundant. I haven’t checked if ‘ select count desc’ works (probably it shouldn’t)

Comment: Would it be better if I said that the select method call is only a projection, not an operation? And `.desc` is a description? The action being performed is to sort/order the table, which requires a column description, and you can optionally project columns after that operation?

Comment: I am still finding it tricky to conceptualize. But I suppose having `desc` in column makes sense esp. if sort uses multiple columns (like `ds.sort($"col1", $"col2".desc)`. It is more intuitive - sort the DS based on 2 columns, col1 should be asc (default) and col2 should be desc)